# MySQL Add Custom Charset to utf8mb4 not utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic, arabic-support

I need to add a custom charset to MySQL server in order to enhance the search experience and I was actually able to to do but into utf8_charset not the mb4 version of it. and I can't seem to find even in MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-character-set.html) anything regarding the mb4

as they mentioned in the documentation I edited the file `/usr/share/MySQL/charsets/Index.xml` and under the `<charset name="utf8">` I added my subset since I could not find any subset for `utf8mb4`

```
 <collation name="utf8_arabic_ci" id="1029">
   <rules>
     <reset>\u0627</reset> <!-- Alef 'ا' -->
     <i>\u0623</i>        <!-- Alef With Hamza Above 'أ' -->
     <i>\u0625</i>        <!-- Alef With Hamza Below 'إ' -->
     <i>\u0622</i>        <!-- Alef With Madda Above 'آ' -->
   </rules>
   <rules>
     <reset>\u0629</reset> <!-- Teh Marbuta 'ة' -->
     <i>\u0647</i>        <!-- Heh 'ه' -->
   </rules>
   <rules>
     <reset>\u0000</reset> <!-- Ignore Tashkil -->
     <i>\u064E</i>        <!-- Fatha 'َ' -->
     <i>\u064F</i>        <!-- Damma 'ُ' -->
     <i>\u0650</i>        <!-- Kasra 'ِ' -->
     <i>\u0651</i>        <!-- Shadda 'ّ' -->
     <i>\u064F</i>        <!-- Sukun 'ْ' -->
     <i>\u064B</i>        <!-- Fathatan 'ً' -->
     <i>\u064C</i>        <!-- Dammatan 'ٌ' -->
     <i>\u064D</i>        <!-- Kasratan 'ٍ' -->
   </rules>
 </collation>
```

and it's working like charm, however, I can't change my whole DB columns collision to use from `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci` or even the customized one of mine `utf8_arabic_ci`

Comment: I would expect the documentation for utf8 to apply to utf8mb4.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's only for utf8 and I can't even cast a query to use utf8mb4, thus I really would like to know how to extend or modify the uft8mb4 charsets

Comment: Please clarify:  Are you talking about `CHARACTER SET` or `COLLATION`?  The former says what characters exist, such as Emoji exist only in utf8mb4.  The latter refers to ordering, such as whether Spanish `ll` comes before `lm` or after `lz`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to add a whole new charset
see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ldml-collation-example.html

```
<charset name="utf8mb4">
  ...
  <collation name="utf8mb4_phone_ci" id="1029">
    <rules>
      <reset>\u0000</reset>
      <i>\u0020</i> <!-- space -->
      <i>\u0028</i> <!-- left parenthesis -->
      <i>\u0029</i> <!-- right parenthesis -->
      <i>\u002B</i> <!-- plus -->
      <i>\u002D</i> <!-- hyphen -->
    </rules>
  </collation>
  ...
</charset>
```